# React Native build failed: 'React/RCTBridge.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build a React Native app with the following file structure:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-app kurtpeek$ tree -L 1
.
├── README.md
├── __tests__
├── android
├── app.json
├── assets
├── index.js
├── ios
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
└── yarn.lock
```

The `package.json` is

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "concurrently 'emulator @Nexus_5X_API_27_x86' 'yarn android-noavd'",
        "android-noavd": "react-native run-android",
        "android-px": "concurrently 'emulator @Pixel_2_API_27' 'yarn android-noavd'",
        "android:release": "cross-env ENVFILE=.env.release yarn run android",
        "android:staging": "cross-env ENVFILE=.env.staging yarn run android",
        "build:android:dev": "cross-env ENVFILE=.env ./android/gradlew assembleRelease -p ./android/",
        "build:android:release": "cross-env ENVFILE=.env.release ./android/gradlew assembleRelease -p ./android/",
        "build:android:staging": "cross-env ENVFILE=.env.staging ./android/gradlew assembleRelease -p ./android/",
        "clean": "concurrently 'rimraf ./android/build/' 'rimraf ./ios/build/' 'rimraf node_modules/' 'yarn cache clean'",
        "codepush": "yarn codepush:ios; yarn codepush:android",
        "codepush:android": "code-push release-react Lucy-Eng/LucyApp-Android android",
        "codepush:ios": "code-push release-react Lucy-Eng/LucyApp-iOS ios --plistFile ios/LucyApp/Info.plist",
        "codepush:ls:apps": "code-push app ls",
        "codepush:ls:deploys": "echo iOS && code-push deployment ls Lucy-Eng/LucyApp-iOS; echo ANDROID && code-push deployment ls Lucy-Eng/LucyApp-Android",
        "codepush:promote:android": "code-push promote Lucy-Eng/LucyApp-Android Staging Production",
        "codepush:promote:ios": "code-push promote Lucy-Eng/LucyApp-iOS Staging Production",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 7'",
        "ios8": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 8'",
        "ios:release": "cross-env ENVFILE=.env.release yarn run ios",
        "ios:staging": "cross-env ENVFILE=.env.staging yarn run ios",
        "iosx": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone X'",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "log:android": "react-native log-android",
        "log:ios": "react-native log-ios",
        "react-devtools": "react-devtools",
        "start": "./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "analytics-react-native": "^1.2.0",
        "immutability-helper": "^2.5.0",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.1.10",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "moment": "^2.19.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "querystring": "^0.2.0",
        "raven-for-redux": "^1.3.0",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-native": "^0.53.3",
        "react-native-android-keyboard-adjust": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native-code-push": "^5.3.2",
        "react-native-config": "^0.11.5",
        "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.5.1",
        "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
        "react-native-intercom": "^8.0.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.4",
        "react-native-markdown-renderer": "^3.1.0",
        "react-native-material-kit": "git://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit#95b0980",
        "react-native-material-menu": "^0.2.3",
        "react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
        "react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.6",
        "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.1",
        "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.27",
        "react-native-sentry": "^0.35.3",
        "react-native-smart-splash-screen": "^2.3.5",
        "react-native-snackbar": "^0.4.3",
        "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.0",
        "react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
        "redux-form": "^7.3.0",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "^4.10.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "reselect": "^3.0.1",
        "validator": "^10.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
        "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
        "code-push-cli": "^2.1.6",
        "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
        "enzyme": "^3.1.1",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.4",
        "eslint": "^4.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-reactnative": "^1.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.1.0",
        "jest": "21.2.1",
        "react-devtools": "^3.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>src/test-config/enzyme-config.js"
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
            "./assets/fonts/"
        ]
    }
}
```

and there is an `ios/Podfile` like so:

```
target 'LucyApp' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'BatchedBridge',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # 'RCTBridge',
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'Intercom'
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'
  pod 'SentryReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sentry'

  # Add new pods below this line

end
```

When I try to build this app in Xcode, I get an import error from `SentryReactNative`:

[image]

Similarly, when I try to run the simulator using `yarn ios`, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/react-native-sentry/ios/RNSentry.m:1:
In file included from /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/react-native-sentry/ios/RNSentry.h:4:
/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridge.h:12:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:

    Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
(1 command with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SentryReactNative.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNSentryEventEmitter.o /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/react-native-sentry/ios/RNSentryEventEmitter.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LucyApp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LucyApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Following https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies, I thought at first that I might need to add `'RCTBridge'` to the `subspec`s of `'React'`, which is the reason for the commented-out line in the `Podfile`. However, if I uncomment that line and try to `pod install`, I get a "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions" error:

[image]

How can I update the imports to make the app build?

Comment: I have to say I tried all the above solutions but only that helped me

   "pod install"

In the command line in the IOS folder

Answer (score 9):

Follow the below steps. It's worked for me.

1. Open `terminal`
2. Go to the `ios` folder
3. Quit `Xcode`
4. run `pod install`
5. Open `.xcworkspace` file.
6. Clean (`cmd+shift+k`) and build (`cmd+b`) the project.

That's it. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this -

- In Xcode, go to the project scheme (Product -> Scheme -> Manage Scheme -> double click your project).
- Click on the 'Build' option at the left pane.
- Uncheck 'Parallelize Build' under Build Options.
- Then in Targets section, click '+' button then search for 'React'.
  Select it and click 'Add'.
- 'React' should now appear under Targets section. Click and drag it to
  the top so that it will be the first item in the list (before your project).
- Clean the project and build.

For more options check the issue on RN repo -
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12042

Comment: I tried this but got stuck at the 'Targets' step - there's no 'React' entry there.

Comment: Done these steps but getting the same error. Little help, please.

Comment: I have tried re-installing node_modules and some other solutions for this issue. But no luck here. 
please help me out @thomasbabuj

Comment: try to upgrade your cocoa-pods version, it may solve.

Comment: @akshay, I tried adding React and it did not work, are you sure you don't mean `React-Core`?

Comment: If your React entry is missing, make sure that you opened the xcworkspace file, not the xcproj file

Comment: If React is missing then you can click on + icon and add React

Comment: there is no option for react

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/issues/142#issuecomment-587551072

As above post suggests.

To properly link @react-native-community/cameraroll if your app is using pods.

Instead of adding libRNCCameraroll.a add libreact-native-cameraroll.a to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me, no hack (advised only if you're not using Swift):

1. File > Project Settings
2. On Built System choose > Legacy Build System (Both)
3. In the same window, Open and Clean your DerivedData dir
4. Clean your Built, Product > Clean
   Save all and restart the Xcode. Happy Coding!

Comment: cleaning derived data?

Answer (score 0):

For me to solve the issue that was occurring was done by adding all this dependencies in `Podfile`:

```
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
```

After adding dependencies and running this commands:

1. `cd ios`
2. `rm -rf Pods`
3. `pod deintegrate`
4. `pod install`

Hope this will solve someone issue too.